# Python: what is the proper way to pass arguments to threading.Thread instance

Tags: python, multithreading

I have extended threading.Thread - my idea is to do something like this:

```
class StateManager(threading.Thread):
    def run(self, lock, state):
        while True:
            lock.acquire()
            self.updateState(state)
            lock.release()
            time.sleep(60)
```

I need to be able to pass reference to my "state" object and eventually to a lock (I'm quite new to multi-threading and still confused about the necessity of locking in Python). What is the proper way to do it?

Comment: It is not very clear for me what you need by looking to your code... by the title of your post, it seems to me that you might be after a synchronized queue: http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

pass them in the constructor, e.g.

```
class StateManager(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, lock, state):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.lock = lock
        self.state = state            

    def run(self):
        lock = self.lock
        state = self.state
        while True:
            lock.acquire()
            self.updateState(state)
            lock.release()
            time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: I was thinking to do that but then I'm overriding the default arguments __init__ has, am I not?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.Thread : "If the subclass overrides the constructor, it must make sure to invoke the base class constructor (Thread.__init__()) before doing anything else to the thread."

Comment: @Veseliq or you can introduce some getter and setter for `StateManager`

Answer (score 8):

I'd say that it's easier to keep the `threading` part away from the `StateManager` object:

```
import threading
import time

class StateManager(object):
    def __init__(self, lock, state):
        self.lock = lock
        self.state = state

    def run(self):
        lock = self.lock
        state = self.state
        while True:
            with lock:
                self.updateState(state)
                time.sleep(60)

lock = threading.Lock()
state = {}
manager = StateManager(lock, state)
thread = threading.Thread(target=manager.run)
thread.start()
```